# How to set the page properties when a new workbook is created?

Tags: excel, vba

I created VBA code that will take an active sheet and the visible cells and create a new workbook, named correctly and attached as an email to send.

However, the newly created spreadsheet when opened from the email is set to no scaling so when it prints, what should be one page is now 4.

While it is easily fixed by manually changing the page setup in the newly opened workbook before printing, I am trying to set the page properties (scaling percent, fit all columns, or whatever I choose) when the new workbook is created.

```vb
Sub Mail_ActiveSheet()

    Dim Source As Range
    Dim Dest As Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    Dim TempFileName As String
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set Source = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Source = Range("A1:H75").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Source Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The source is not a range or the sheet is protected, please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Set Sheetname = ActiveSheet
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set Dest = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)

    Source.Copy
    With Dest.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With

    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
    TempFileName = "Lost Items for " & Sheetname.Name & " " & Format(Now, "mm-dd-yy")

    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
    Else
        FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
    End If

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With Dest
        .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .Display
            .to = "someone@somwhere.com"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "Lost Items for" & " " & Sheetname.Name
            .HtmlBody = "Please see the attached spreadsheet.  Have a nice day." & .HtmlBody
            .Attachments.Add Dest.FullName
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        .Close savechanges:=False
    End With

    Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
With Dest.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    .Cells(1).Select
    'insert your parameters here
    .PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$Z$12"
    .PageSetup.Zoom = False
    .PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 1
    .PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
    'end of section
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With
```